# Spark alternatives for reading incomplete files

Tags: file, apache-spark, corrupt

I am using Spark 2.3 to read Parquet files. The files average about 20mb each and currently have about 20,000 of them. The file directories are partitioned down to the day level across 24 months.

The issue I am facing is that on an occasional basis most of the files are rewritten by an Hbase application. This does not occur every day, but when it does it takes several days for that process to complete for all files. My process needs to look at the data in ALL files each day to scan for changes based on an update date stored in each record. But I am finding if I read the HDFS dir during the period of the mass file rewrite, my Spark program fails and I get errors like these:

java.io.EOFException: Cannot seek after EOF

**OR**

java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=hdfs://project/data/files/year=2020/month=02/day=10/file_20200210_11.parquet

**OR**

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: hdfs://project/data/files/year=2020/month=02/day=10/file_20200210_11.parquet is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail

I assume the errors are because it is trying to read a file that is not finalized (still being written to). But from Spark's perspective it looks like a corrupt file. So my process would fail and not be able to read the files for a couple days until all files are stable.

Code is pretty basic:

```
val readFilePath="/project/data/files/"

val df = spark.read
    .option("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", "true")
    .parquet(readFilePath)
    .select(
       $"sourcetimestamp",
       $"url",
       $"recordtype",
       $"updatetimestamp"
    )
    .withColumn("end_date", to_date(date_format(lit("2021-08-23"), "yyyy-MM-dd")))
    .withColumn("start_date", date_sub($"end_date", 2))
    .withColumn("update_date", to_date($"updatetimestamp","yyyy-MM-dd"))
    .filter( $"update_date" >= $"start_date" and $"update_date" <= $"end_date" )
```

Is there anything I can do programmatically to work around a problem like this? It doesn't seem like I can trap an error like that and make it continue. In Spark version 3 there is an option "spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", that I think would help, but not in version 2.3 so that doesn't help me.

I considered reading a single file at a time and loop through all files, but that would take forever (about 12 hours based on a test of just a single month). Outside of asking the application owner to write changed files to a temp dir then move and replace them as each is completed into the main dir, I don't see any other alternatives so far. Not even sure if that would help or if I would run into collisions during the small period of time the file was being moved.

Comment: An idea related to your idea using a temp folder: you could let the HBase application write the new parquet files into a new subfolder in HDFS. As long as the HBase application is still writing the new files, your Spark application reads from the original folder. As soon as the HBase application is ready, the Spark application switches to the new folder and the old folder can be deleted.

Comment: That might be an option, costs more HDFS space, but would help the stability of my extract